# Bean marked with @Configuration fails in creation and fails startup of application

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, jetty-8

I have a Spring MVC app created using spring 4.1.0.RELEASE. I have a class say A which has been marked with @Configuration to mark it as a configuration class.

The XML config in application context is as below

```
<bean id="a" class="A"></bean>
```

The application is failing on startup with the following error. I'm using eclipse with jetty 8 plugin.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: A(class name)(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:548)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:861)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:791)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:381)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:478)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1052)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:356)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:323)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:32)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:373)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:365)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1009)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The strange part is that the application run fine on all my team mates systems but not on mine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe your java version is different than others?

Comment: We have a project specific java setting and it is using java 1.6 its the same on everyone's machine

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError occurs if there is some issue with the jar loaded. I think in your machine you are trying to run this code on, has CLASSPATH set to some path which is loading the older version of the jar.

1. It is possible that lower version of Spring jars may exist in your share folder or in class path.
2. If it is maven project,do mvn dependency:tree and check any other dependency is loading lower version of spring.
3. You can see paths of all jars loaded in your application.

> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
> URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader();
>                       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
>
> }

Comment: 1. I have checked the class path but i don't see any earlier version of spring 2. It is a maven project and i ran a dependency tree command on it but could not find any problems                                                                          3. I have checked the paths of the jars that are loaded in the application and it is being loaded from my local maven repository

Comment: I doubt some other A class exist in parent class loaders which does not have default constructor. If you can debug your code in start up of application, keep debug point at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean() api and in  watch, check classloader of A class with this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("A")   this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("A").getClassLoader().Please revert with result.

Comment: With the debugger enabled i tried looking at the variables when the control reaches inside the doCreateBean but could not find where to get that information from and i can't modify the source of this class to add the line of code you gave. I enabled the verbose mode in vm arguments which gives the class loading but could not find anything fishy since all classes are loaded from my local .m2. Also i made an observation that spring container first creates beans when loading context and then start destroying them midway and then the bean in question is recreated and cached eagerly any idea why?

Comment: I was able to get the values so this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("A") -> class A and this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("A").getClassLoader() - > WebAppClassLoader=Spring MVC Application.

Comment: So A class is loaded in your WebApp CL,so A class is loaded from your application itself. So now,Does A class have any super class or interface ? Can you provide A class structure ?

Comment: It does not have any super class or interface. Its just a config class which is annotated with @Configuration and defines one more bean.